# Не кормите троллей!

Tags: обсуждение, faq, модерация, тревоги

Бывает, что на сайте публикуются откровенно провокационные и оскорбительные вопросы или ответы.

Что в таких случаях надо делать:

- Если сообщение содержит оскорбления в адрес кого-либо:

  - Отметьте тревогой типа «оскорбительный» — 6 тревог обеспечат удаление сообщения; также эти тревоги видны модераторам;
  - Поставьте минус сообщению;
  - Проголосуйте за удаление, если можете.
- Если это просто провокация на неконструктивный спор — отметьте тревогой для модератора и кратко опишите ситуацию;

Что НЕ НАДО делать:

- Возражать,
- Оставлять комментарии,
- Публиковать ответы на провокационный вопрос.

Таким образом вы поддаетесь на провокацию, кормите тролля и поощряете повторные провокации. Потом модераторам и другим участникам приходится тратить время на расчистку и тревоги.

Игнорируйте все попытки провокации. Самое неприятное, обидное и фрустрирующее, что вы можете сделать троллю — не обращать на него внимания.

Не кормите троллей!

Comment: Но, если троллей кормить, то на их творчестве можно фармить тревоги и повышать общий балл на выборах в модераторы...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я же обращаюсь ко всем, а не только к фармящим общий балл для выборов. )

Comment: @Discord хм. Когда-то слышал, что лучше отметить все комментарии, так будет проще удалять. Хотя, может, неправильно помню... Надо спросить у Nofate

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: если удаляется конфликтный вопрос, то все комментарии удалятся вместе с ним. Нет необходимости отмечать каждый.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Бывают случаи, когда вопрос нормальный, но в комментариях начинается спор, я скорее про такие говорил

Comment: Кто-то писал, что в таком случае помечать надо всё равно вопрос/ответ, а не комментарии. А помечать только первый комментарий вроде нехорошо.

Comment: @Discord: Проверил: очередь не завалится, там показывается одно сообщение со списком тревог на нём и комментариях под ним. Прорабатывать тревоги довольно удобно, когда привыкнешь. Так что лишние тревоги на комментариях помогают.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: вы были правы. По крайней мере мне так удобнее удалять.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как бороться с некачественными вопросами?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418)