# Новая политика неверно опубликована и нарушает предыдущие политики. То есть новую политику можно не соблюдать?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, генеративный-ии, кризис-2023

[Новая политика модерации сообщений, сгенерированных AI](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12758/) была [опубликована с нарушениями некоторых правил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389597/please-follow-your-own-policies-on-making-new-policies) (нарушенные правила указаны в посте, но приведу их и здесь):

> Stack Exchange, Inc. соглашается с тем, что будет:
> [...] Размещать предварительные просмотры для просмотра всех новых официальных политик в экземпляре групп модераторов с тегом политики, помеченных ссылками на их общедоступную версию после публикации, и поддерживать список всех официальных общесетевых политик со ссылками на них в Справочный центр.
> [...] Объявить об изменениях модераторского соглашения не менее чем за шестьдесят дней до крайнего срока принятия нового соглашения со сроком не менее тридцати дней для обсуждения и рассмотрения.

> #### Где я могу найти эти политики?
>
> Упомянутые политики в настоящее время находятся на Meta Stack Exchange. Все официальные политики на MSE будут помечены тегом [mod-agreement-policy], который предназначен только для персонала, и к ним будет применена блокировка политики.
> Возможно, что политики могут появиться в других местах, таких как Справочный центр или блог. Если это произойдет, на эту страницу будут добавлены ссылки, чтобы их можно было легко найти.
>
> #### Когда и как вводятся новые политики Stack Exchange, Inc.?
>
> Если возникнет необходимость в новой политике, она будет сначала написана и передана Совету модераторов. Затем он пройдет через процесс обратной связи и возможные итерации, прежде чем будет представлен модераторам из команды модераторов стека. Эти будущие политики затем будут опубликованы на MSE и получат тег [mod-agreement-policy], обозначающий их статус.

Что из этого было исполнено? Изначально эту новую политику получили только модераторы (как я понял), а потом её [опубликовали](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content) в пересказе с [искажением смысла](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content#comment1299185_389583) на MSE. Выполнения остальных пунктов "политики о создании новых политик" я не вижу.

#### Вопрос:

1. Правильно ли я понял ситуацию?
2. Политика опубликована не по правилам, значит её можно не соблюдать?

Comment: Это все равно что: "Новый закон противоречит конституции! Значит его можно не соблюдать?"

Answer (score 5):

Там на самом деле много нестыковок в политиках по отношению к GPT. На текущий момент разногласия администрации и сообщества SE по этим вопросам [не улажены](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12778/373567), поэтому пока что рано принимать решения о валидности GPT-политик, либо о вами указанных недочетах в процессе их публикации.

Мы продолжим поддерживать качество контента на «Stack Overflow на русском» так же, как это делали раньше. Будут новые вводные — будут приняты новые решения.

Comment: То есть если я вижу gpt-шный мусор, то ставить тревогу модератору, и модератор удалит этот мусор? Просто недавно моя такая тревога была отклонена.

Comment: @Зонтик уберите из своего вопроса "gpt-шный" и ответ станет очевидным. Мы редко удаляем вопросы и ответы, только если совсем жесть. Неправильный ответ - это тоже ответ, его можно заминусовать, если вопрос плохой - закрыть и т.д. На самом деле удалять ответы могут не только модераторы, но и сообщество. Для этого нужно иметь достаточно репутации, у вопроса должен быть отрицательный рейтинг и набрано 3 голоса на удаление, работает так же как с закрытием вопросов. Голосуйте "против" - это основной инструмент для указания на качество ответа, тревоги предназначены для крайних случаев.

Comment: Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy): *"Если вы увидите содержимое, опубликованное другими участниками, которое, вероятно, сгенерировано, сообщите об этом модераторам **с помощью сигнала тревоги**."*

Comment: @Зонтик я не говорил, что с этим что-то не так. Но не полагайтесь только на тревоги, модератор это не первая инстанция, а последняя (ну почти последняя). Голосуйте, комментируйте, не забывайте об этих возможностях.

Comment: @aepot [Не кормите троллей!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2171/548252)

Comment: @PeterKolosov у меня к ним иммунитет.